# GUI and server application

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a question regarding WPF and server application. I was given a task to write a simple TCP server with a GUI. I'm new to C# (and GUIs in general), hence I have a question.

I have 2 classes:

**App.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
        if (e.Args.Length != 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Wrong number of arguments!", "An error has occured", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }
        window.Show();
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ShowConnectionsButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            LogsTextBox.Text += "text\n";
    }
}
```

that are both initially generated by Visual Studio. I assume that MainWindow.xaml is for handling GUI-related stuff and App.xaml is for application's logic. So, my (simple) question is, how should I start the server part? Should it be

```
server = new Server();
server.start();
window.Show();
```

or maybe

```
window.Show();
new Thread(() =>
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
    server = new Server();
    server.start();
}).Start();
```

or maybe use `BackgroundWorker`?

Comment: You should never use `new thread` like that to spool work, you should use the async await pattern.  You should create a task that is executed, rather than a raw thread.

Comment: The second one may cause you some heartache when the reference to your thread gets GC'd and suddenly your server stops for no reason.

Answer (score 1):

Where you put the server logic will depend on how you want your UI to behave.

Usually, you will want the window to load separately with loading/retrieving data.

You could put your server call in the [Loaded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded?view=netframework-4.7.2) event. For example:

```
public void OnLoad(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   server = new Server();
   server.start();

  ...
}
```

This will be called when the window has loaded, and can be started. How you update data bindings will depend on how your server object is built.

Comment: I should have mentioned this is in the MainWindow.xaml.cs file.